# Can this expression be simplified?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am running code from a `Room` object to get all the `IRoomDwellers` of a specific type into a list. All `IRoomDwellers` are stored in a static `Dictionary<IRoomDweller,Room>`.

However, this is basically my first time using `Linq`, and I feel (though the code appears to work) that the expression is rather unwieldy. For one, I don't *really* get what value the `GroupBy` is adding, but it does not appear to work without it.

The method is as follows:

```
private List<T> GetDwellers<T>() where T : IRoomDweller {
    return RoomDwellers
        .GroupBy(z => z.Value)
        .SelectMany(z => z)
        .Where(z => z.Value == this && z.Key is T)
        .Select(z => (T) z.Key)
        .ToList();
}
```

What function does the GroupBy actually serve (I cribbed that from an example when my initial attempt didn't work)? And can this expression otherwise be simplified/made to be more performant?

Comment: `.SelectMany(z => z)` is redundant - it doesn't do anything here.

Comment: I agree that `GroupBy` seems pointless, as it cancels out with `SelectMany`. What "didn't work" when you deleted the `GroupBy` and `SelectMany`?

Comment: the `GroupBy` followed by the `SelectMany` looks weird indeed. Effectivly it "sorts" the list by `Value`. I guess you could simplify it to `RoomDwellers.Where(z => z.Value == this).Select(z => z.Key).OfType<T>().ToList();` but the result would be sorted differently.

Comment: @phuzi I figured, but the code won't work without it. I cannot separate out the key/value pair in the Where if I don't have it.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot separate out the key/value pair"? Do you get an error message? Do you get something different from your expected output? If so, what is your expected output and actual output?

Comment: @Sweeper SelectAll by itself does not pass on a value from which I can extract a key/value pair. Value is not exposed in the Where, in that case (though Key is).

Comment: @RenéVogt That looks much cleaner! Had no idea OfType was a thing (though from what I can tell it COULD still be lumped into the Where). Ordering is fairly irrelevant as long as I can iterate over the results.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal to have a dictionary (which is intended to be used to get a Room, if you have a RoomDweller) and use it the wrong way round (you have a Room and want to get a RoomDweller) but:

```
return RoomDwellers.Where(rdkvp => rdkvp.Value == this && rdkvp.Key is T)
  .Select(rdkvp => rdkvp.Key)
  .ToList();
```

RoomDwellers is a list of KeyValuePair, Key is a RoomDweller, Value is a Room.. So you can enumerate the list of KVPs, choosing those where the Value is this room, and then return the associated Key (the RoomDweller)

Comment: That won't allow me to only get a specific type of RoomDweller, will it? And, yeah, it's not ideal, but it seems the only way to prevent double-storing my values (as I need access from RoomDweller to its room, too).

Comment: Then you should really have two dictionaries, one for each mapping direction or if (as the data structure seems to imply) a RoomDweller may only have a single Room, that could be a property of the Dweller, whereas the Room has a list of Dwellers.

Comment: I want to avoid keeping two bits of data in sync like that. Surely you must understand that? Too prone to errors...

Comment: Then you create a class that houses both dictionaries and whose sole purpose in life is to keep them in sync; a bi-directional dictionary per se. I'm happy to admit there are a lot of things I don't understand, people wanting to put the things they will look up in the value side and the data they want to get in return as the key side of a dictionary, for example. Dictionaries work on hashtables in the direction of key -> value and are very, very fast. When you want to look things up in the direction of value->key they are dog slow because it requires a looping construct to visit every value

Comment: A room can have multiple occupants. Bidi won't work. Thanks though, you are providing great insights to think about.

Comment: That's why you have a `Dictionary<Room,List<RoomDweller>>`, or perhaps simpler, just model these things as properties of the Room/RoomDweller themselves (Room.RoomDwellers list, RoomDweller.Room field).. If this were a database with a 1:M Room:Dweller, EF would probably have already generated it that way :) - I do find it a bit odd that a Room seems to have a dictionary of RoomDweller:Room so rooms know about other rooms and dwellers. I'd expect these dictionaries to be external to both Room and Dweller, kinda like an index in a db is not within a table but an external reference to data in it